# If I receive Google verification codes that do not work, is my phone compromised?

Tags: multi-factor, gmail, sms

I know that something similar has happened to other people before (see for instance [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173914/which-telephone-numbers-do-google-use-for-two-factor-verification-codes?newreg=16c4d65012634556a20999d844a4ac87) or [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240624/received-a-call-from-1-202-455-8888-but-i-did-not-attempt-to-log-in-to-my-gmail)), but the situation and the question are slightly different.
I wanted to log in to my Gmail account from my laptop, and usually I receive a verification code to my phone number, sent by "Google". This time it was sent from some random phone number, and **it did not work**. I tried a few more times to get a code. Every time it was sent from a different international phone number and had some **oddities** (wrong spacing or spelling), but **the timing was almost seamless** (it arrived perhaps 2-3 seconds after I had requested it, while usually it takes roughly 1 second). I did not try to use them anymore, as I was growing suspicious. I cleared the cookies and browsing history of my iPhone, restarted it, retried again to get a code, and still got a similar message from some random number. I tried again and then I got a usual message from Google, used the code, it worked, and then I changed my Gmail password (just to be safe). But now I am wary of using my phone for the 2-step verification process: it looks like someone is getting the message from Google instead of myself, and then is sending me a fake code (though I would not know why). I want to stress that I do not get these messages at random times (as other people on the internet have mentioned), but rather **shortly after having actually requested a code**. Does this mean that my phone has been compromised (though I would not know how...), and if so, what can I do about it?

Comment: This looks exactly like the linked questions.

Comment: It doesn't, in the following ways: in one link the code did work, in the other link it arrived at a random time. And in any case, the question is different: I am not asking whether the phone number is from Google (I am quite confident it is a scam, because of oddities in the texts) but rather whether (/how) my phone might have been compromised and whether it's still safe to use it.

Comment: We cannot possibly tell if/how your phone was compromised by this behavior. And the first one you link is an exact duplicate,

Comment: I misread - it took a while

Comment: I know you cannot tell whether my phone is compromised or not, but maybe someone knows whether this event is plausible also on an uncompromised phone. In other words, my question is: is it possible (and if so, how?) that I get those messages at precisely the right moment (though they are scam), and that I do not get the original messages from Google, unless my phone has been compromised?

Comment: There is nothing in your scenario to suggest that anything is compromised. If your phone was compromised, then the sending numbers and text would not be unusual.

Comment: Yes, it's plausible and I linked to a few questions where this topic is discussed. The *only* issue is that the codes did not work. And that can be explained if the codes came from a different time zone, which mean that the codes had already expired.

Comment: Thanks. Though (last question...) the texts also had spelling mistakes (like "your Google verification otp" instead of "code"), that makes me think that they were not just sent by Google and messed up somehow, but rather sent by some scammer... or do you think they came from Google anyway?

Comment: That's covered by the last link I provided above